# ReactJS Best way to conditional rendering component with props

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering

Now my Container looks like this. But i don't think it's best way.

```js
renderAddForm() {
  if (!this.props.isFetching) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }
  return <AddForm {...this.props} />;
}

render() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <PageHeader title="Ангилал нэмэх" button="Хадлгалах" href="#" />
      {this.renderAddForm()}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution it's fine.
Another way could be inline:

```
render() {

  let { isFetching } = this.props

  return (
    <Layout>
      <PageHeader title="Ангилал нэмэх" button="Хадлгалах" href="#" />
      {isFetching ? <div>loading</div> : <AddForm {...this.props} />}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the OP solution is totally fine. I would advice against inlining things, as it may get messy and hard to visualize.

Comment: In this case I don't find that inline is messy at all